# Methods and buttons connect in Java

Tags: java, button, methods

I'm trying to link a button to a method, where the user will have to enter their name, GPA, and ID. 
here is the code

***In the main method:***

```
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String name = txt2.getText();
        String ID = txt2.getText();
        String GPA = txt3.getText();
        addNewStudent();

    } 
});
```

***Method in the same class***

```
public static void addNewStudent() {
    String name =
    String IDnum = scanner.nextLine();
    String GPA = scanner.nextLine();
    Student newStudent = Student.createStudent(name, IDnum, GPA);
    if (studentInfoSystem.addNewStudent(newStudent)) {
        System.out.println("New student added: name = " + name + ", ID = " + IDnum + " GPA: " + GPA);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot add, " + name + " already on file");
    }
}
```

I want to know how to connect them.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently, you are not familiar with the concept of [method parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

If you want to get information into a method, you have to pass that information in as a parameter. Instead of declaring your method like this:

```
public static void addNewStudent()
```

you'd declare it like this:

```
public static void addNewStudent(String name, String id, String gpa)
```

This method signature means that when you call `addNewStudent()`, you have to give it three arguments of type String, like this:

```
String name = txt2.getText();
String ID = txt2.getText();
String GPA = txt3.getText();

// this line has been modified. look!

addNewStudent(name, ID, GPA);
```

Then, inside `addNewStudent()`, you can do whatever you want with those passed arguments:

```
Student newStudent = Student.createStudent(name, id, gpa);
```

Some advice: Java is case sensitive. Normally, you name variables in lowercase, with an uppercase character for any new words in the variable name. Don't get ahead of yourself and try doing things before you understand what's going on. Your grasp of Java seems tenuous at best. Spend time studying the tutorial I linked above and you will find that you don't have to ask these kind of basic questions anymore.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters in add new student then assign them to variables

```
public static void addNewStudent(string _name ,int _id , float _gpa)
```